# How to get rounded decimal only in JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is is possible to get rounded decimal? Added 0 if number is not decimal.

I've bootstrapvue table like this

```
<b-table
  style="white-space: nowrap;"
  hover
  responsive
  class="position-relative"
>
  <template #cell(weight)="data">
    {{'@ '+data.item.weight+ '/' + (data.item.weight*data.item.qty) + ' kg'}}
   </template>
</b-table>
```

my case is in weight multiplication arithmetic x qty above.

when value weight x qty(14.8 x 21)=312.90000000000003
then I want to round to 3 decimal digits using toFixed(3) it will produce (312.900) as I expected.

but when weight x qty(10 x 2) = 20
when it comes to the looping table which by default uses .toFixed(3) it returns 20.000 .

I don't expect the value of 20.000, because I need the number 20 only, and only want to round the decimal number to use toFixed(3) only.

what if a non-decimal number doesn't have 3 trailing zeros using toFixed(3) ?

Comment: `let num = Value % 1 === 0 ? Value : Value.toFixed(3)` this should solve your problem

Comment: Number.isInteger() is part of the ES6 standard and not supported in IE11.
It returns false for NaN, Infinity and non-numeric arguments while x % 1 != 0 returns true.

Comment: siddhat sankhe 

I've tried 
```<template #cell(volume)="data">
            {{'@'+(data.item.volume) + '/' + ((data.item.volume*data.item.ctns) %1 === 0) ? (data.item.volume*data.item.ctns) : (data.item.volume*data.item.ctns).toFixed(3) + 'm3'}}
          </template>```
but that not work

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
let yourNumber =  weight x qty;
if (!Number.isInteger(yourNumber)) {
   yourNumber = yourNumber.toFixed(3);
}
```

Where weight and qty are variable, replace them with your values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.floor an Math.ceil function as well if you want to round it to nearest decimal number. But you might have to write extra login to check
whether fractional part of the number is greater or less than 0.5.